# How do you fake twitter data from the twitter-gem?

Tags: ruby, mocking, twitter-gem

I have a working script that uses the twitter gem in order to pull information from twitter. However I cannot find a way to fake this data for testing without actually calling out to twitter.

Does anyone know of a way to mock this? I'd be up for even writing this by hand, I just cant figure out the proper format.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use the [VCR gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr). It will record API calls once, then save them to a YAML file to be replayed. You can re-record them if they get out of date as well.